# Why doesn't my session load when switching locales?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next-i18next

I am using Next.js in combination with `next-auth` and `next-i18next`.

I use `useSession()` (with the `next-auth/client` Provider in my _app.js) to check if the user is authenticated. Once authenticated, navigation is very quick and the current session is kept between page renders. Until I switch the locale. After switching, the `loading` state (coming from `useSession()`) switches to `true`.

The `loading` state stays true, until I focus to another browser tab and come back.

I would hope the session would also be kept between locales, just like it is kept between page navigations...

I have no idea why this is happening, and if this behavior is normal.

To switch locales I use:

```
<Link href={router.asPath} locale="en">EN</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try to add getSession to getServerSideProps. it worked for me.

```
    import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react'

    export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      const session = await getSession(context)
      const authorized = !!session?.jwt
      return {
        props: { authorized },
      }
    }
```